# How can I define a static method in JavaScript to use with or without parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a ES6 Vehicle class defined below. I want to have a static method such that I can use with or without parenthesis. I have defined `static AvailableTypes` and `static  AvailableTypes()` but it gives an error `TypeError: Vehicle.AvailableTypes is not a function`

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor({ vehicleType = 'car', name = '', range = '', seats = '' }) {
    this.vehicleType = vehicleType
    this.name = name
    this.range = range
    this.seats = seats
  }

  getRangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  get rangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  static AvailableTypes = ['car', 'plane']
  static  AvailableTypes() {
    return this.AvailableTypes
  }
}

const vehicle = new Vehicle({ name: 'My Car name', seats: 500, wheels: 45 })
console.log(Vehicle.AvailableTypes) // (2) ['car', 'plane']
console.log(Vehicle.AvailableTypes()) //TypeError: Vehicle.AvailableTypes is not a function
```

This should result in `availableVehicleTypes` being `['car', 'plane']`

```
const availableVehicleTypes = Vehicle.AvailableTypes;
```

This should also result in `availableVehicleTypes` being `['car', 'plane']`

```
const availableVehicleTypes = Vehicle.AvailableTypes();
```

Comment: Give different names to the method and the array.

Comment: But the task is to access it with the same name

Comment: That's impossible.

Comment: Javascript doesn't support overloading.

Comment: What I have done above is not true but can we do it maybe with static set ?

Comment: @Nalin Ranjan: How would that even be overloading?

Comment: For objects there's a way to store two separate values with the same property name (the other being in the underlying prototype, technically the values would be stored in separate objects), but even then you can access only a single value at the time. It's also possible with functions (a class is actually a function), but provides you to modify the underlying prototype of the function, which is not recommended, and there's still a single value to access at the time.

Comment: A car with 45 wheels? Now I'm curious :P

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to create a value that is both a function and an array.

Make up your mind and choose only one of the two, it'll be much less confusing to the users of your class.